Preventing fatal errors, but allowing most errors to trigger rescue block
I have an Ansible playbook that is designed to reach out to a hundred or so devices and run a specific task. Some of these might be offline, but I need to track which failed and have a ticket generated each time. I have found the simplest solution to that would be an email to our ticketing system using the community mail module.
- name: Backup configuration...
  block:
    - name: Backup configuration....
      ansible.builtin.uri:
        validate_certs: no
        url: "https://{{  ansible_host  }}/api/blahblahblah"
        return_content: yes
        method: GET
      register: configuration_string
  rescue:
    - name: Email notification for failed host...
      community.general.mail:
        host: "{{  email_server  }}"
        port: "{{  email_port  }}"
        secure: try
        from: "{{  email_secrets  }}"
        to: "{{  email_to  }}"
        subject: "Device {{  inventory_hostname  }} was unable to be backed up"
        body: |
          Connection failed on {{  inventory_hostname  }}...
        username: "{{  email_secrets  }}"
        password: "{{  email_secrets  }}"
      connection: local
    - name: Halt remaining tasks for unreachable host...
      ansible.builtin.meta: end_host

My catch appears to be that a failed connection attempt is treated as a fatal error, preventing any further plays from being run, including the rescue block. I need to find a way to ignore the fatal status, but still trigger a failure event if it is unable to connect.
Is there a good way to make that happen?
